# Properly center uiviews inside their parentView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a slot `UIView()`. i have subclassed `UIView()` and everything is working just fine.

Now i'm trying to use autolayout to support ipads too.

Here's what i want:

[image: img1]

What i have achieved:

```
public protocol GDTextSlotDelegate: class{
    func onTextEntered(_ finalText: String)
}

@IBDesignable
final public class GDTextSlot: UIView, UIKeyInput {
    public weak var delegate: GDTextSlotDelegate? = nil

  / ... /
}
@IBInspectable
public var numberOfSlots: Int = 4 {
    didSet{
        / .. /
    }
}

 @IBInspectable
public var baseWidth: CGFloat = 30.0 {
    didSet{
        / .. /
    }
}
```

Also generating a new slot:

```
/// Calculate X position of slot and make sure
/// the whole group is always in center of the view
private func calcX() -> CGFloat{
    return ((frame.width - (baseWidth * CGFloat(numberOfSlots))) / 2) + (CGFloat((currentSlot - 1)) * CGFloat(baseWidth))
}

private func calcFrame() -> CGRect{
    return CGRect(x: calcX(), y: 0, width: baseWidth, height: frame.height)
}

/// Initiate a new label for the slot!
private var label: UILabel{
    let lbl: UILabel = UILabel()
    lbl.frame = calcFrame()
    lbl.text = "_"
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.white
    lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    lbl.tag = currentSlot

    return lbl
}
```

Final step:

```
public func generateSlots(){
    for index in 1...numberOfSlots{
        currentSlot = index
        addSubview(label)
    }
    currentSlot = 1
}
```

But, Adding AutoLayout on the storyboard makes the view wide on ipad, which's fine. but the slots doesn't center.

Here's my debug hierarchy on `iPad`:
[image: s]

I'd appreciate any solution with either with code or autolayout, Thanks

Comment: You need set horizontal view center equal parent view center and then change multiplier for constraint

Comment: Well, thank you. I wouldn't ask if i knew to :D i'm new to autolayout

Comment: @RawandAhmad Is `frame` the frame of the parent view?

Comment: @RawandAhmad Do you mind posting an image of the result of your current code(not storyboard)?

Comment: @RawandAhmad Check my answer, and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@canister_exister has a good solution for the storyboard approach. Doing it in code is pretty simple, too. In your case, use `UIStackView`:

```
public func generateSlots(){ 
    //Stack View
    var stackView = UIStackView()

    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter
    stackView.spacing = //spacing between each label
    for index in 1...numberOfSlots{
        currentSlot = index
        var slotLabel = UILabel()
        //customize your label here: don't need x and y
        //these are width and height constraints for each label
        view3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        view3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: baseHeight).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
    }
    currentSlot = 1

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stackView)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First set constraints for each child view 
[image]

Second for each child view change Align Center X Multiplier

[image]

Multipliers should be 0.25 for first, 0.75 for second, 1.25 for third and 1.75 for fours

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Can i do that in code? I can't really do it with storyboards

Comment: Sure you can do it in code, but that's a lot of code and not fast. In storyboard it took me 2 mins and no code

Comment: @RawandAhmad It shouldn't be to much hassle to mimic the pictures in code

Answer (score 1):

When you have an equal arrangement of some arbitrary number of objects like this, use a UIStackView. This screen shot shows an example:

[image]

The stack view is a horizontal stack view with center alignment and fill equally distribution. The stack view has a constraint horizontally centering it in its superview (and an arbitrary height constraint and top constraint, both irrelevant for this example). That causes its arranged subviews — the slot views — to be equally spaced and sized and the whole thing centered in the stack view's superview.

Let's analyze how we get the specific results that we get.

- The heights of the slot views are determined by their height constraints.
- The spacing between the slot views is determined by the spacing setting of the stack view.
- Thus, the only thing left to specify is the width of the slot views; that is set by the width constraint of the stack view itself. Knowing the desired width of a slot view, you just multiply that width by the number of slot views, multiply the stack view spacing by one less than the number of slot views, add those two together, and set the stack view width constraint constant to that.

The slot views thus end up looking exactly the same, and centered horizontally in their superview, no matter what size the superview is. And the really cool part is that we can increase or decrease the number of slot views and it all continues to work perfectly, because the stack view does all the work of arranging them.